# Where clause changing the results of my datediff column, How can I work around this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, datediff

I'm trying to obtain the time elapsed while st1=5. Here is what I currently have, which gives me the datediff time for each state change. My issue is that when i add a where st1=5 clause the datediff shows the difference in time between instances where the state = 5 instead of time elapsed where state is 5.

```
select timestamp,st1,st2,st3,st4,
  datediff(second, timestamp, lead(timestamp) 
    over (order by timestamp)) as timediff
from A6K_status
Order By Timestamp DESC


+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| st1 | st2 | st3 | st4 | TimeStamp           | TimeDiff |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 2018-07-23 07:51:06 |          |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:50:00 | 66       |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 0   | 0   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:47:19 | 161      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:39:07 | 492      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 3   | 3   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:37:48 | 79       |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 3   | 3   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:37:16 | 32       |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
```

I am trying to sum the time that the state of station1 is 5. From this table above(what I have right now) if i could just sum timediff Where st1=5 that would work perfectly. But by adding "where st1=5" to my query gives me the time difference between instances where the state = 5.

Any help would be much appreciated. I feel very close to the result I would like to achieve. Thanks you.

Edit
This is what I would like to achieve

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| st1 | TimeStamp  | TimeDiff |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 5   | 2018-07-23 | 558      |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

Comment: can you post what the expected results should be? The question was hard for me to follow what it is you actually want. But generally speaking, you could use a `CASE` expression with the `WHERE` clause logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a subquery (or CTE):

```
select sum(timediff)
from (select timestamp, st1, st2, st3, st4,
             datediff(second, timestamp, lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) as timediff
      from A6K_status
     ) s
where st1 = 5;
```

Comment: This is solved thanks to Gordon, Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, try something like this:

```
WITH SourceTable AS (
select TOP 100 PERCENT timestamp,st1,st2,st3,st4,
  datediff(second, timestamp, lead(timestamp) 
    over (order by timestamp)) as timediff
from A6K_status
Order By Timestamp DESC
)
SELECT SUM(timediff) as totaltimediff
WHERE st1 = 5
```

Comment: Error I recieved: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Oops. I thought LEAD/LAG also fixed that. Adding TOP 100 PERCENT to inner query.

Comment: Why even have the order by in the cte? But more importantly this won't work as there is no FROM in the final select. Not sure the cte is needed though, just aggregation should do it. Does seem to be close though.

Comment: Because of the `LEAD` - although that was just a bit of fuzzy thinking on my part (*blush*). It just shows that my coffee level was too low.